# Unrecognized Selector Sent to UIView Instance Error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I know theres a few solutions to this error on StackOverflow already, but I couldn't find one specific to my problem.

I'm trying to create a custom view for the Google Maps marker info windows using:

```
- (UIViewController *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker {

DMinfoWindow *view =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DMinfoWindow" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        view.firstName.text = self.firstName;
        return view;
    }
```

I have created a UIViewController called DMinfoWindow, which has the a UILabel named firstName and is linked to an IBOutlet.

If I comment out the "view.firstName.text = self.firstName;" line, it works fine and when I click on a marker the custom view appears.

However, with the line included I get the following error:

```
2013-06-23 17:58:52.763 ExerciseBuddy[1406:1a003] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView firstName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1623a6e0'
```

Any help on this error would be great! I assume that something is not in memory that should be but I'm not sure what.

Many thanks

Comment: Did you set the Custom Class attribute in Interface-Builder?

Comment: It's currently set to UIView, but faded out. I tried to change it to UIViewController but it just reverts back to UIView faded out.

Comment: This is the view item, set it your infoview class.

Comment: Edit your post to include the declaration of `DMInfoWindow` (the `@interface` block, including the declaration of the `firstName` property).

Answer (score 0):

> '-[UIView firstName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Now, translate this:

```
    view.firstName.text = self.firstName;
```

To not using dot notation:

```
    [[view firstName] setText: [self firstName]];
```

Assuming that is the only line of code that mucks with `firstName`, then there are two possible places it could fail.

Given that it is complaining about `UIView` not implementing that method, I'm betting it is the `[view firstName]` that is failing.   Are you sure `view` is an instance of `DMInfoWindow`?   That assumption that the first object in the array from the nib loading expression is exceptionally fragile.   You should have an outlet that is explicitly connected to the object desired from the XIB file.

Comment: I changed the code to `DMinfoWindow *view = [[DMinfoWindow alloc] init]` to make sure it was an instance of DMInfoWindow but still the same error. The label has an outlet.

Comment: @DJDMorrison that is unlikely to solve your problem; you are now creating a view that isn't in the view hierarchy.  However, if that didn't fix it, then are you sure that `self` has a `firstName` method or property when that method is executed?